# gradle build not detecting android ndkVersion in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, build.gradle

I am trying to test an android demo of [pocketsphinx](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialandroid/) which uses aars libraries. When I run `gradle installDebug`, it crashes:

```
> Task :wear:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED
Task :wear:stripDebugDebugSymbols in app Starting
Gradle local properties file not found at /home/abhin/android/sphinx/local.properties
android.ndkVersion from module build.gradle is not set
ndk.dir in local.properties is not set
ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable is not set
sdkFolder is /home/abhin/android-sdk
Because no explicit NDK was requested, the default version '21.0.6113669' for this Android Gradle Plugin will be used
Considering /home/abhin/android-sdk/ndk-bundle in SDK ndk-bundle folder
Considering /home/abhin/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6011959 in SDK ndk folder
Rejected /home/abhin/android-sdk/ndk-bundle in SDK ndk-bundle folder because that location has no source.properties
Rejected /home/abhin/android-sdk/ndk/21.0.6011959 in SDK ndk folder because that NDK had version 21.0.6011959 which didn't match the requested version 21.0.6113669
Task :wear:stripDebugDebugSymbols in app Finished
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/install-ndk) it states that gradle 4.0.0 (*which i'm using*) defaults to ndk v21.0.6113669, but also it says that

> For AGP version 3.6 and above, that NDK version will be used to build
> your projects if you do **NOT** specify an NDK version in the build.gradle
> file

So in app/build.gradle, I have set:

```
android {
    ndkVersion '21.0.6011959'
}
```

But still, the error is showing up. I ran `gradle clean` but couldn't get through.

I'm using gradle installed universally with version 6.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work at last. The reason for the build fail was that the project folder had another folder `wear`, which had same kind of files that `app` folder has, like `build.gradle`, `src` folder, etc. So in the `build.gradle` of `wear` folder, I set the ndkVersion to the version I had locally. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My gradle build was failing during CI in Azure DevOps. My error message was so similar to the OP's that I thought my problem was also NDK version:

```
 1 > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols FAILED
 2  Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols in app Starting
 3  Gradle local properties file not found at /Users/runner/work/1/s/MyApp/android/local.properties
 4  android.ndkVersion from module build.gradle is not set
 5  ndk.dir in local.properties is not set
 6  ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable is /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
 7  sdkFolder is /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk
 8  Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.
 9  Considering /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle by ANDROID_NDK_HOME
10  Considering /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle in SDK ndk-bundle folder
11  Considering /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/21.4.7075529 in SDK ndk folder
12  Considering /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858 in SDK ndk folder
13  Considering /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/18.1.5063045 in SDK ndk folder
14  Considering /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670 in SDK ndk folder
15  No user requested version, choosing /Users/runner/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/23.0.7599858 which is version 23.0.7599858
16  Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols in app Finished
```

The difference is at line 8: `Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.`

The build output was littered with "Support for ... is deprecated" messages so I never considered this was the problem. It was. When I ran the build with debugging output (`build --debug`) I discovered the deprecation warning was fatal:

```
[WARN] [com.android.build.gradle.internal.cxx.logging.ErrorsAreFatalThreadLoggingEnvironment] 
Support for ANDROID_NDK_HOME is deprecated and will be removed in the future. Use android.ndkVersion in build.gradle instead.
```

Later, I also disovered there was a warning in microsoft app centre:

> Gradle Task failures may be related to NDK 23 requiring gradle plugin 4.0+. If you use older gradle plugin version please downgrade to NDK 22 or lower.

- I chose to upgrade the plugin.
- I had an older version of Android Studio. When I upgraded to 11.0.10 it included a new feature which identified that I needed up update the Android Gradle Plugin.
- I updated AGP to 4.2.1
  This fixed the problem for me.